# Should LMGTFY be banned?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, lmgtfy

On StackOverflow, lmgtfy.com is banned by a word filter, because it's insulting and because it's not in keeping with the goals of the site which is to be a encyclopedia of sorts of answers to common and uncommon questions. [Someone](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35098/something-like-php-net-for-ruby-on-rails) decided to post an lmgtfy.com link as an answer to a question here on programmers.stackexchange.com. Should the same word filter be installed here too?

Comment: If there's one site in SE where LMGTFY might be appropriate, Programmers would be it...

Comment: Where's the down-vote comment? :)

Comment: @Mr Crt: Why would Programmers be the site?

Comment: @Ken: this site is targeted at "subjective discussions"... Questions that can be effectively answered via a Google search (that is to say, by **a** result of a Google search, not by *the aggregate results* of a search) are arguably off-topic. Contrast with SO's "no question too easy" mantra.

Comment: @Mr. CRT, so we should close them or migrate them to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Ken: the latter requires moderator intervention. The former doesn't teach the author anything.

Comment: @Mr. CRT -- nevertheless, that's what these functions are for. You can't give up on properly moderating the site because it's too hard, or because you feel sorry for the person asking. They can easily go to StackOverflow and ask the question. Even so, we still shouldn't allow LMGTFY answers on such questions because it's insulting. If you're going to have pity on the guy who posted on the wrong site, have pity all the way and give a proper answer.

Comment: What's LMGTFY? -

Comment: @muntoo well played.

Comment: Why not put it in the comments? LMGTFY should be in the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I added this to the blacklist for programmers.

Comment: Gasp! I demand freedom! I deman- BANNED.

Answer (score 18):

My feeling is that if they did away with it on SO, then that should be the rule for us and all of the other SE sites.  There's no value added to an answer from there.

Comment: Agree, lmgtfy is degoratory (where is the dictionary for bad spellers?) in a snide way.

Comment: @Thor: Not to completely destroy the purpose of this question, but: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=degoratory

Answer (score 7):

No, it shouldn't be banned. In fact it's a good hint that the question be closed.

If a question provokes a [working] LMGTFY answer then it is a poor question.

You say it's insulting to get that kind of response. But don't you think it might also be insulting to folks here to see you didn't bother to google first, then you didn't bother to put some effort into your question and then you will likely not bother to accept an answer?

BTW, did you bother to check if there are discussions already of this matter?

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ban+lmgtfy+on+stackoverflow&l=1

Comment: Why not just downvote the question? Or vote to close it?  What's the value added by including an LMGTFY answer?

Comment: @Walter: teaching tool. Give a man a fire, he'll be warm for a day...

Comment: ....Throw a man into a fire, he probably won't visit your house again.

Comment: @Zoot : ... at least not without flame-retardant underwear.

Comment: @Mr. Crt, ... set the man on fire, he'll be warm for the rest of his life.

Comment: @Thorbjørn However short that may be. >:)

Answer (score 6):

Testing...

Maybe you can find your answer [here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Ban+LMGTFY).

Edit:
Hmm... Doesn't seem to be banned. Strange. I'm looking into it.

Update:
No, LMGTFY links are *not* banned on Programmers-SE. Each site has a unique black list and it has not been added to Programmers-SE. The [feature-request] should be sufficient to raise the issue. Vote it up if you want it implemented or raise on meta.Stackoverflow, if you feel it should be a network-wide feature.

Answer (score 3):

The technical aspect of the ban (blacklisting lmgtfy.com links in posts) might not be active, but it's my understanding the practice effectively is banned for all the reasons pointed out in the original [Ban lmgtfy (let me google that for you) links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) question on Meta Stack Overflow.

There isn't a context in which they are helpful or constructive on a site where one of the main sections in the FAQ is [Be Nice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#benice). If you see it being used, I suggest flagging it for moderator review.